# Bind a WPF ComboBox Based on Data From Another ComboBox Using JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, data-binding

I have two comboboxes, one displays the country data, while the second displays cities.

I am binding these combobox using deserialized data from a JSON file structured this way:

```js
[
  {
    "country": "Albania",
    "city": [
          "Elbasan",
          "Petran",
          "Pogradec",
          "Shkoder",
          "Tirana",
          "Ura Vajgurore"     
      ]
  }
]
```

Deserializing it and extracting the data like this:

```c#
public partial class SomeUCClass: UserControl
{      
    readonly UtilityMethods utilityMethods = new UtilityMethods();

    private string jsonFilePath = @"C:\SomePath\CountryData.json";

    public ObservableCollection<AllCountriesData> countryCityData { get; set; }

    public SomeUCClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        countryCityData = new ObservableCollection<AllCountriesData>();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void SomeUCClass_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath))
            {
                string actualJsonFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllCountriesData>>(actualJsonFile);
                foreach (var countryCityDataObject in x)
                {
                    countryCityData.Add(new AllCountriesData() { Country = countryCityDataObject.Country, Cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { countryCityDataObject.MyString.ToString() } });
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            utilityMethods.ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }


    }


  }

public class AllCountriesData
{
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<string> Cities { get; set; }
  public string MyString
  {
     get { return Convert.ToString(Cities); }
     set { }
  }
}
```

Finally binding it to the comboboxes like so:

```xaml
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbCountry" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding countryCityData}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Country"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="CmbCities" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding countryCityData}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Cities"/>
```

The results of this process is that the "Country" combobox ends up being populated, while the "City" combobox displays a series of items labelled (Collection).

Here's the screenshots of both scenarios.
[image: "Country" Combobox Display]

[image: "Cities" Combobox Display]

What I'd like is for the "Cities" combobox to display the respective cities attached to the "Country" combobox.

What/Where I'm I doing/going wrong and how can I remedy this?

Comment: Your naming of classes and properties is misleading. But... Bind Selecteditem of CmbCountry to another property. Bind CmbCity itemssource to ThatSelectedPropertyYouJustAdded.City ( which should be cities ). Implement inotifypropertychanged in your viewmodels and raise property changed when you set that new property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the second `ComboBox` to the `Cities` property of the `SelectedItem` of the first one:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Cities, ElementName=CmbCountry}"/>
```

There is no need to set the `DisplayMemberPath`here since `Cities` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=CmbCountry}"/>
```

Or more usually you would just have a `SelectedCountry` on your VM.
eg

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding countryCityData}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Country" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}"/>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCountry.City}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"/>
```

Your `AllCountriesData.City` would be better named `AllCountriesData.Cities` since it it a collection of multiple cities.

Comment: No DisplayMemberPath necessary? Also would you happen to know why my CmbCities combobox displays the text (Collection) instead of the actual data?

Comment: Your city combo has it's CollectionSource set to countryCityData. This is a colleciton of countries, not cities. You then tell the combo to display the "City" member of each country. "City" is a collection of cities, so wpf calls ToString() on the collection which results in "(Collection)"

Comment: @Chesaro: Just bind to the Cities property. See my answer.

Comment: @Chesaro: Did you select a country?

Answer (score -1):

I admit that I initially didn't know what I was doing. But after reading up on the ObservableCollection class, both the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)  as well as the simplified [C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/) version, I have a firmer grasp on things.

I tweaked my code starting with the C#, I changed the 'Cities' properties into a list of JSON object by replacing what was an ObservableCollection with a List and decided against creation a new object on deserialization :

```
public partial class SomeUCClass: UserControl
{      
    readonly UtilityMethods utilityMethods = new UtilityMethods();

    private string jsonFilePath = @"C:\SomePath\CountryData.json";

    public ObservableCollection<AllCountriesData> countryCitiesData { get; set; }

    public SomeUCClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        countryCityData = new ObservableCollection<AllCountriesData>();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void SomeUCClass_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath))
            {
                string actualJsonFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllCountriesData>>(actualJsonFile);
                foreach (var countryCitiesDataObject in x)
                {
                    countryCitiesData.Add(new AllCountriesData() { Country = countryCitiesDataObject.Country, Cities = countryCitiesDataObject.Cities });
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            utilityMethods.ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }


    }


  }

public class AllCountriesData
{
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

I then applied @GazTheDestroyer's (which was also later suggested by @mm8) fix to my XAML:

```xaml
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbCountry" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding countryCitiesData}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Country"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="CmbCities" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Cities, ElementName=CmbSupplierCountry}"/>
```

With these fixes I am now able to comfortably display the country alongside it's cities (thank God) as shown below:

[image: "Country" ComboBox Display]

[image: "Cities" ComboBox Display]